# excel Method 'open' of object 'workbooks' failed error when opening a read only workbook

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling

I have code that should open open a handfull of workbooks, pull key info and close them. i can see the workbook loading but then when it is about to open i get the runtime error 1004 that says

> Method 'open' of object 'workbooks' failed

My code is as follows and when i debug it takes me to the 2nd line under the do while statement:

```
 Sub OEEsummmary()
Dim Gcell As Range
Dim MySheet As Worksheet
Dim Txt$, MyPath$, MyWB$
Dim myValue As Integer
Dim x As Long
Dim v As Variant, r As Range, rWhere As Range

MyPath = "L:\Manufacturing Engineering\Samuel Hatcher\"
x = 2
Set MySheet = ActiveSheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Do While MySheet.Range("A" & x).Value <> ""
    MyWB = MySheet.Range("A" & x).Text
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=MyPath & MyWB, ReadOnly:=True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True
    Set Gcell = ActiveSheet.Range("E21")
        With MySheet.Range("A" & x)
            .Offset(0, 7).Value = Gcell.Value
        End With
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    x = x + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

I tried to change the different defined variable to variant as per instructions of other people who had the same issue but nothing worked. Any help is greatly appreciated thanks!

update* I moved the two file names that were an issue to the bottom of the list and every other file name opened and copied the info perfectly but when the loop got to the last two files it gives me that error. all of the files are manipulated copies of the bottom 2 so i dont see why it doesnt work

update2* it seems as though the only workbooks that give the error and wont load are the ones open on another computer in the network, when this program is run all the workbooks will  be open on other computers

Comment: What is the value of `MyWB` when the error occurs?

Comment: @Dave OEE 1173.xlsm

Comment: And this file is definitely present in the specified location? You have not added any trailing or leading spaces in Cell A2 that would invalidate the filename?

Comment: @Dave nope i just checked for those, check out my update at the bottom of my question, also it recognizes that the file is there and loads it but then when the loading bar is done it gives me that error

Comment: If you're opening an `xlsm` file, maybe set `Application.EnableEvents` to false before you open the file.  Could be it has code it's trying to execute that updates somewhere in the workbook on open but it can't because you're opening it read only?

Comment: All of the files are .xlsm so i dont see why just the one would mess up, ill try that though

Comment: @Dave i just tried it and it still gave me the same error in the same place

Comment: Are you able to open those files manually from Excel itself?

Comment: @DougGlancy yes, but they are read only, as are the other files that work

Comment: Workbooks.Open will fail like that if the file is already in the application. Double check that the workbooks aren't open already (they could be left open because you were working on them, or they might be hidden in some invisible instance of Excel). You could either restart Excel and run it fresh, or manually check the Workbooks object in the debugger (add a watch).

Comment: @Mikegrann all of the workbooks i am accessing are open on other computers within the network when this sub is run, but the last two are the only ones giving me issues. that is why i added "ReadOnly:=True, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True"

Comment: @Vbasic4now The specific issue I'm talking about should only occur if the workbooks are open on *your* computer (specifically in the same instance of Excel), because it's an inability to have duplicate workbooks open at the same time. So if you personally don't have those workbooks open on your computer, then it isn't the issue - whether or not others have it open remotely makes no difference. I'd still encourage looking carefully at the `Workbooks` Object just to make sure.

Comment: @Mikegrann how do i go about checking that?

Comment: @Vbasic4now Hmmm, if you don't know how to use the debugger then the easiest way might just be to execute something like `Sub NotifyOpenBooks() For Each wb In Workbooks MsgBox wb.FullName Next End Sub` (sorry for formatting, comments have issues). This will just pop up a messagebox for every open workbook (annoying, but it works). If the paths to your problem files don't popup, then something else is the issue.

Comment: @Mikegrann i did that and the only open work book on my computer is the one im writing the code in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it turns out a few of the files were corrupted so when the code encountered this it didnt work. the solution to this problem was to close the corrupted workbook then when I reopened it I clicked the arrow next to open and selected "open and repair" then saved a new copy of the file and the code ran smoothly